# Drive Table Lock Timeout

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm getting the following error when I try to load my app, and not sure why. It seemed to appear randomly. What might cause this to appear?

*Drive Table internal error. Please try again. Caused by: Lock timeout: another process was holding the lock for too long.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like this was caused by a query I was running from a Suggest Box.